# Django - permission_required on view level

Tags: django

I am looking at the built-in authentication functionality from Django for my custom app. 
If I understand this right, I can assign add, change, delete rights to models.

I am looking for a solution to assign view/show rights to a user.

My basic idea is to use the permission_required decorator for this, but as stated this only works for add, change, delete and in addition it seems only to work for models. I have functions where I am using multi-objects from models.

The best would be to have something that collects my custom permission_required decorators and gives me the possibility to edit this e.g. in the Django admin UI.

E.g.

```
@permission_required('user.profile.view')
def myProfile(request):
...

@permission_required('user.profile.edit')
def editMyProfile(request):
...
```

Any idea or suggestion is welcome.

Thanks in advanced!

Comment: Nothing prevents you from creating your own custom permissions, that can be as fine grained as you want. There is also the `user_passes_test` decorator if your authorization logic is more complex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating custom permissions is [well documented](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/auth/customizing/#custom-permissions). Once you've created custom permissions, you'll be able to assign them to users through the usual user admin page.

Comment: This was maybe more a problem of understanding the methodology behind this on my side.